# Site name is not changing in <title>

Tags: 8

When I change the site name in admin/config/system/site-information it has no effect on the site name between the title tags. It always shows "Drupal" as the site name.

I'm using the Basic theme with the same implementation as in the core themes:

```
<title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

I already checked the translations and the site name is also not hard coded in settings.php

Comment: It goes without saying, but have you cleared your Drupal caches?

Comment: 1 million times .D

Comment: nobody an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem, and I solved it after reading this article:

Source : https://www.drupal.org/node/2844755

you can do it step by step :

1. Change the default language to English.
2. Delete the other language.
3. Clear the cache.
4. Change the site name.
5. Add the other language and set it back to default.

It works after adding new language again

Comment: Yes, I discovered this thread too in the meantime and solved the problem. Just forgot to mention in here.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to change the front page title of my drupal 8 site
I have done it by Jquery, and used the following code in the front page twig file.

document.title="new title";

It worked for me